# array does not work after move to PHP5.4

Tags: php, arrays

EDIT: I added my entire code om the bottom of this post  My code below worked fine in PHP 5.3 but it is returning empty results in PHP 5.4  What is causing it?

This is the code I am using:

```
$xaxis=array();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $chachg_time = $xml->xpath("//ns:BulkData[ns:Name='ChannelChangeHistory.{$i}.ChannelChangeTime']/ns:Value");
        $chachg_time = $chachg_time[0]; 
        $xaxis[] = $chachg_time[0];
     }
```

In PHP 5.3, I get the following result (which is what I am expecting):

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 6
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 6
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 6
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

)
```

In PHP 5.4 I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

Here is the original workig code with php 5.3 Version

```
require_once ('jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/src/jpgraph_line.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/src/jpgraph_scatter.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/src/jpgraph_date.php');


$dir = realpath(getcwd());
$pattern = '/\.(xml)$/'; // check only file with these ext.          
$newstamp = 0;            
$newname = "";

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {               
       while (false !== ($fname = readdir($handle)))  {            
         // Eliminate current directory, parent directory
         if (preg_match('/^\.{1,2}$/',$fname)) continue;            
         // Eliminate other pages not in pattern            
         if (! preg_match($pattern,$fname)) continue;            
         $timedat = filemtime("$dir/$fname");            
         if ($timedat > $newstamp) {
            $newstamp = $timedat;
            $newname = $fname;
          }
         }
        }
closedir ($handle);

$feed = file_get_contents($newname);
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("ns", "urn:broadband-forum-org:ipdr:tr-232-1-0");

// RUN CHANNEL CHANGE HISTORY SCRIPT // 

        $yaxis=array();
        $xaxis=array();

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 32; $i++) {
                $chachg_time = $xml->xpath("//ns:BulkData[ns:Name='InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.1.X_ATT_ChannelChangeHistory.{$i}.ChannelChangeTime']/ns:Value");
                $chachg_time = $chachg_time[0]; 
                if ($chachg_time == "") 
                    {
                    break;
                    }       
                else {

                    $xaxis[] = date("M-d h:i:s A", strtotime($chachg_time[0]));
                    $ch = $xml->xpath("//ns:BulkData[ns:Name='InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.WLANConfiguration.1.X_ATT_ChannelChangeHistory.{$i}.Channel']/ns:Value");
                    $ch = $ch[0];
                    $yaxis[]=$ch[0];
                    }
                }               
                foreach ($xaxis as $k => &$v) {
                    $a = (array)$v;
                    $v = $a[0];
                }
                foreach ($yaxis as $s => &$t) {
                    $b = (array)$t;
                    $t = $b[0];
                }



// Width and height of the graph
$width = 1000; $height = 800;

// Create a graph instance
$graph = new Graph($width,$height);

$graph->setMargin(50,50,40,200);
// Specify what scale we want to use,
// text = txt scale for the X-axis
// int = integer scale for the Y-axis
$graph->SetScale("textint",0,50);

// Setup a title for the graph
$graph->title->Set('');

// Setup titles and X-axis labels
$graph->xaxis->title->Set('');
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($xaxis);
//$graph->xaxis->scale->SetDateFormat('H:i');
$graph->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(90);
$graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_FONT2);

// Setup Y-axis title
$graph->yaxis->title->Set('Channel');
$graph->yaxis->scale->SetAutoMax(11); 
$graph->yaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT2);
$graph->yaxis->SetTitlemargin(25);
 // Create the bar plot

$sp1 = new ScatterPlot($yaxis);
$sp1->mark->SetType(MARK_FILLEDCIRCLE);
$sp1->mark->SetFillColor("#61a9f3");
$sp1->mark->SetWidth(8);


// Add the plot to the graph
$graph->Add($sp1);

// Display the graph
$graph->Stroke();

?>
```

Comment: Looks ok to me (in that you are getting `SimpleXMLElement` objects). Using `var_dump` or `print_r` on `SimpleXMLElement` is practically useless so do not rely on it for actual data / debugging purposes

Comment: I doubt that this is your problem, there might be another part of code which is causing the problem.

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan , I included complete code.

Comment: @Phil how else can this be debugged?

Comment: @user2755910 Why does it need debugging? Just look at the XML and use the Simple XML library to work with it

Answer (score 1):

Your results are not empty, only dumping `SimpleXMLElement` doesn't show any useful data.

Access and dump data from these objects and you'll see.

For more detail see also comments in [SimpleXMLElement documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).